# Is there an easy way to create a month/year date picker that shows multiple months at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a web application which requires a month/year date to be entered (day of the month does not matter).

Currently I am using an input of type month:

```
<input type="month">
```

This renders really nicely on an iPhone, but the user interface in the Chrome browser is hideous - it displays all the individual days of the month and you have to scroll to previous/future months a single click at a time.

I've had a look at javascript date pickers like jquery (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) but that has the same problem. I am happy to adapt or extend something if it doesn't quite fit. Can anyone suggest a good date picker with sensible behaviour on normal screens and also touch screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to show only month of the year.  Since you're interested in plugins, I would like to suggest [**`bootstrap datepicker`**](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) which has this feature by default.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

**Rendered output:**

[image]

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/357/)